# Image not showing in ActionBar on Android

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to put our logo as an image in the ActionBar. I have an icon as my navigation and it shows but the image will not.

The drawer icon is showing fine and is in the location as the logo image.

```
      <android>
        <NavigationButton icon="res://drawer" @tap="toggleDrawer()" />
        <Image src="res://myimage" stretch="none"></Image>
      </android>

      <ios>
        <NavigationButton visibility="hidden"></NavigationButton>
        <ActionItem icon="res://drawer" ios.position="left" @tap="toggleDrawer()" />
        <Image src="res://myimage"></Image>
      </ios>
    </ActionBar>
```

iOS displays the image but Android does not. On Android, `myimage` is in the same location as `drawer` which is displaying.

Comment: try putting the image, inside a layout e.g. GridLayout

Comment: Thanks @Narendra that was it. I had tried it with a StackLayout previously but had a v-if on it as well so neither image showed up. On Android I could only get the v-if to work if the image was in an ActionItem. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting Image inside a `Layout` will help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumble upon this. I have found that have to add `app` directory in path like this:

`~/app/images/yourimage.png`